# How can I add GET parameters to the URL after submitting a form

Tags: forms

I am trying to add certain parameters to my URL after submitting a form. I have a module which uses HOOK_form_alter and I am wondering if it is possible to add these parameters to the form so that they appear in the URL when a user clicks to submit the form.

Comment: are you wanting to change the form submission URL and add parameters to that? just add them to form['#action'] as GET parameters. Or are you wanting to change the url after submitted - then do you want a redirect after submitted to this new url with added parameters?

Comment: Yes I think just to use form['#action'] yes?

Comment: Ideally it should only add the parameters if the form is submitted without errors

Comment: to do that you need to hook submit so it can check for errors, then if ok, do a redirect to your new url having those parameters added to the url.